# creating XML elements and values from table data

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that stores data:

```
declare @t table
    (
        el nvarchar(50), 
        val nvarchar(50)
    )
insert into @t values ('n1', 'value 1'), ('n2', 'value 2'), ('n3', 'value 3 <>')
```

I should get xml, that look like this:

```
<data>
  <n1>value 1</n1>
  <n2>value 2</n2>
  <n3>value 3 &lt;&gt;</n3>
</data>
```

the best I could get so far is:

```
select cast('<' + el + '>' +  (select val from @t i where i.el = t.el for xml raw(''), elements)  + '</' + el + '>'  as xml)
from @t t
For XML Raw(''), root('data'), Elements, Type
```

Could you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to join on `el` and you can use `*` to remove the tag name `val`.

```sql
select cast('<'+el+'>'+(select val as '*' for xml path(''))+'</'+el+'>' as xml)
from @T
for xml path(''), root('data')
```

Result:

```xml
<data>
  <n1>value 1</n1>
  <n2>value 2</n2>
  <n3>value 3 &lt;&gt;</n3>
</data>
```

Comment: +1 Nice trick!  Is there any documentation about using `*` with `for xml` ?

Comment: @Andomar [Columns with a Name Specified as a Wildcard Character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500154.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the `val` attribute to XML:

```
cast((select val for xml path(''), type) as nvarchar(max))
```

That will give you `<val>value 3 &lt;&gt;</val>`, but you can strip off the `<val>` tags with replace:

```
select  cast('<' + el + '>' + 
        replace(replace(
            cast((select val for xml path(''), type) as nvarchar(max)), 
            '<val>', ''), '</val>', '') +
        '</' + el + '>' as xml)
from    @t
for     xml path(''), root('data')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 you may try XML PATH

```
    SELECT TOP 1000 FirstName, LastName
  FROM [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Person]
  where FirstName like 'Ken%'
  and BusinessEntityID like '1514%'
  FOR XML PATH
```

Output will be

```
<row>
  <FirstName>Kendra</FirstName>
  <LastName>Alonso</LastName>
</row>
<row>
  <FirstName>Kendra</FirstName>
  <LastName>Moreno</LastName>
</row>
<row>
  <FirstName>Kendra</FirstName>
  <LastName>Munoz</LastName>
</row>
<row>
  <FirstName>Kendra</FirstName>
  <LastName>Romero</LastName>
</row>
```

For more examples, please refer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx

Comment: One of the column values becomes the element name.  Your approach won't work for that, try it out.